# Value error of dimension when using scipy ode solver

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

Currently attempting to run the following code

```
import numpy as np

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

from scipy.integrate import ode


def dydt(t,y,tsi,rho):

    Lambda      = 10^-4
    beta        = 0.0065
    lambda2      = 0.08

    rho = interp1d(tsi,rho, fill_value = 'extrapolate')


    #one group delayed precursor
    dydt1 = (-lambda2*y[0] + beta*y[1])
    #power
    dydt2 = (((rho(t)-beta)/Lambda)*y[1]+(lambda2*y[0])/Lambda)
    return dydt1, dydt2


x = 21

dt = 1

tsi=np.arange(0,x,dt)
dt = [1]

rho=np.ones(x)*0.0025
y0= [1,0]
t0 = [0,x-1]


sol = []

i = ode(dydt)

i.set_integrator('dopri5')

i.set_initial_value(t0,y0)

i.set_f_params(tsi,rho)


for t in tsi[1:]:

    i.integrate(i.t+dt)

    sol.append(i.y)
```

But, I end up with this error:

> runfile('C:/Users/----/Desktop/---.py', wdir='C:/Users/---/Desktop')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users---\Desktop---.py", line 46, in 
>      i.integrate(i.t+dt)
>
> File "C:\Users---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate_ode.py", line 432, in integrate
>      self.f_params, self.jac_params)
>
> File "C:\Users---\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate_ode.py", line 1172, in run
>      tuple(self.call_args) + (f_params,)))
>
> ValueError: 0-th dimension must be 2 but got 0 (not defined).

I followed a similar example online but the main difference is that I'm returning 2 equations in my function and my two args are arrays. I've attempted to use odeint and solve_ivp but they give wildly inaccurate answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check again the line

```
i.set_initial_value(t0,y0)
```

in the documentation, the time argument comes second (because it is an optional argument with default value 0). And the initial time is a scalar, not a tuple.

You should define the interpolation function only once, and then pass only this as parameter, or even leave it as global object.

```
sol.append(i.y)
```

might also not do what you think it does, in the vector valued case it builds up an array of identical copies of references to `i.y`. Use `i.y.copy()` to produce a copy that is removed from the internals of the solver.